# Battery usage with MacBook Air

Tags: power-management, macbook

Currently running ubuntu with a macbook air 6

Running into a problem though with the battery. I've managed to lower the overall usage (see outputs) especially when idle, but there is still 50 C plus usage when even just web browsing

auto-cpufreq:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Linux kernel: 5.15.0-83-generic
    Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4250U CPU @ 1.30GHz
    Cores: 4
    Architecture: x86_64
    Driver: intel_cpufreq
    
    ------------------------------ Current CPU stats ------------------------------
    
    CPU max frequency: 1900 MHz
    CPU min frequency: 800 MHz
    
    Core    Usage   Temperature Frequency
    CPU0      2.1%        46 °C       800 MHz
    CPU1      1.1%        45 °C       800 MHz
    CPU2      3.2%        46 °C       800 MHz
    CPU3      5.1%        45 °C       800 MHz
    
    CPU fan speed: 1993 RPM

---------------------------- CPU frequency scaling ----------------------------

Battery is: discharging

Setting to use: "powersave" governor

Total CPU usage: 49.0 %
Total system load: 1.28
Average temp. of all cores: 47.50 °C 

High CPU load (load average: 1.28, 0.88, 0.81)
setting turbo boost: on

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

powertop:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 6.78 W
The power consumed was 158 J
The estimated remaining time is 3 hours, 15 minutes

Summary: 558.5 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 27.6% C

500 mW used by tick_sched_timer and 700 mW by btusb
```

also, just happened to see that dmesg returns

```
[<0000000035b5015a>] dw_dma_interrupt 
[dw_dmac_core]

irq 0: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)

 ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] 00000000e17c1456 (20210730/exresop-66)

ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store] (20210730/dswexec-431)
```